# Is Volley framework in Android is suitable for uploading images and videos?

Tags: android, image, video, upload, android-volley

It was said in the android developers  "Volley is not suitable for large download or streaming operations, since Volley holds all responses in memory during parsing." but how about uploading videos or images? is uploading is including in what they called "streaming operations"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check this article : [here](http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/)

I think it would be better if you use retrofit.

[image: from article]

Each project is its own and should be treated as such.

Comment: does it mean that uploading large files using volley is somehow acceptable?

Comment: @ Earwin delos Santos : Yes. It is .!! But it totally depends on your project requirements..

Comment: Thank you for your great response! I just want to stick to volley for now, but maybe next time I would use retrofit

Comment: @   Earwin delos Santos : Good luck :D

Comment: Anyone has a clue about ion(http://www.koushikdutta.com/ion), in terms of speed which one do you recommend?